# I want to create multiple form in symfony 2 . is it correct way?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, symfony-forms

**This Is my Controller **

public function companyConfigAction(Request $request) {

```
    $form = array();    
    $addCompany = new CompanyAccount();
    $addBankDetails = new CompanyBankAccount();
    $addCompany->addBankDetails($addBankDetails);

    $addCompanyAccountForm = $this->createForm(new CompanyAccountType(), $addCompany);
    $addCompanyCommisionForm = $this->createForm(new CompanyBillingCommissionInfoType(), new CompanyBillingCommissionInfo());
    $companyContactInfo = new CompanyContactInfo();
    $addCompanyContactInfoForm = $this->createForm(new CompanyContactInfoType(), $companyContactInfo);
    $addCompanySubscriptionForm = $this->createForm(new CompanyOtherSubscriptionType(), new CompanyOtherSubscription());

    return $this->render('BillingInvoiceBundle:Company:configuration.html.twig', [
                'entity' => $addCompany,
                'companyAccountForm' => $addCompanyAccountForm->createView(),
                'companyCommissionForm' => $addCompanyCommisionForm->createView(),
                'companyContactInfo' => $addCompanyContactInfoForm->createView(),
                'companySubscription' => $addCompanySubscriptionForm->createView(),
    ]);
}
```

Comment: So you got 4 independent forms which is fine.  Is that what you want?  Or do you want one form with 4 different entities?

Comment: yes i want 4 different  form in 1 page.  and please can u tell me how to inject form.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use all these forms in a single form, than have a look at the collection form type:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html

Comment: Well no.  These are all different types of forms.

Comment: yes all are different forms.  i want to show different form in 1 page

Comment: i m using it in different tabs and different tab have different form.  is there any other way.